# Web crawler script will not run when accessing Internet from another source - Python

Tags: python-2.7, http-status-code-404, mechanize

I have run into an issue where my web crawler will only run correctly when I am connected to my home Internet.

Using Python 2.7 with the Mechanize module on Windows 7.

Here are a few details about the code (snippet below)- This web crawler logs into a website, navigates through a series of links, locates a link to download a file, downloads the file, saves the file to a preset folder, then repeats the process several thousand times.

I am able to run the code successfully at home on both my wired and wireless internet. When I connect to the Internet via a different source (e.g. work, starbucks, neighbor's house, mobile hotspot) the script runs but returns an error when trying to access the link to download a file:

```
httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP ERROR 404: Not Found
```

This is what the prints in the IDE when I access this site:

```
send: 'GET /download/8635/CLPOINT.E00.GZ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: dl1.geocomm.com\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (x11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1\r\nCookie: MSGPOPUP=1391465678; TBMSESSION=5dee7266e3dcfa0193972102c73a2543\r\nConnection: close\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n'
header: Content-Type: text/html
header: Content-Length: 345
header: Connection: close
header: Date: Mon, 03 Feb 2014 22:14:44 GMT
header: Server: lighttpd/1.4.32
```

Simply changing back to my home internet What confuses me is I am not changing anything but the source of the internet - I simply disconnect from router, connect to another, and rerun the code.

I have tried to change the browser headers using these three options:

```
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (x11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11')]
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]
```

I am using the Mechanize module to access the Internet and create a browser session. Here is the login code snippet and download file code snippet (where I am getting the 404 error).

```
def websiteLogin():
## Logs into GeoComm website using predefined credential (username/password hardcoded in definition)

    br = mechanize.Browser()
    cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
    br.set_cookiejar(cj)
    br.set_handle_equiv(True)
    br.set_handle_gzip(True)
    br.set_handle_redirect(True)
    br.set_handle_referer(True)
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(),max_time=1)
    br.set_debug_http(True)
    br.set_debug_redirects(True)
    br.set_debug_responses(False)
    br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (x11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

    br.select_form(nr=0)
    br.form['username']='**********' ## stars replace my actual un and pw
    br.form['password']='**********'
    br.submit()

return br

def downloadData (br, url, outws):

    br.open(url)
    for l in br.links(url_regex = 'download/[0-9]{4}'):
        fname = l.text
        outfile = os.path.join(outws, fname)

        if not os.path.exists(outfile):      
            f = br.retrieve(l.absolute_url)[0]
            time.sleep(7.5)
            shutil.copy2(f, outfile)
```

This code does run as expected (i.e. downloads files without 404 error) on my home internet, but that is a satellite internet service and my daily download and monthly data allotments are limited - that is why I need to run this using another source of internet. I am looking for some help better understanding why the code runs one place but not another. Let me know if you require more information to help troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from your get-request your mechanize browser object is trying to get the resource **/download/8635/CLPOINT.E00.GZ** from host **dl1.geocomm.com**.

When you try to recheck this you will get the 404 because the resource is simply not available.

dl1.geocomm.com is redirected to another target

What I'd recommend you to do is to start debugging your application in an appropriate way.
You could start with adding at least some debugging print statements.

```
def downloadData (br, url, outws):
    br.open(url)
    for l in br.links(url_regex = 'download/[0-9]{4}'):
        print(l.url)
```

After that you'll see how the output differs. Ensure to pass the url in the same way every time.

Comment: Danny, I noticed that when I was troubleshooting initially. However, geocomm has some built-in mechanism for generating a link that points to a specific dataset to download. That link is only good once. For instance, after logging in, if you go [here](http://download.geocomm.com/download.php?catalogid=ATLAS-00009) you'll see a link to download a file. If you refresh the page, that url changes. Since I am accessing the file url immediately after accessing the site, the url should not change (and doesn't when I run the code at home).

Comment: I'm not sure how to check if the resource is 'cached at my gateway'.  Can you elaborate a bit?